# Adobe Reader XI opening file problem

Tags: pdf, extension, gnome-shell-extension, adobe-reader

I have the following error message in AR XI :

> There was an error opening this document. This file cannot be found

when I try to open a `pdf` document by clicking-right on it, both with default application or special script.

If the document is in the last folder I used in AR, it works fine, but if I try to open a file in another directory, I have this error message.

The script I use :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/wine "C:\\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" $1
```

the `desktop` file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Adobe Reader XI
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/nico/.wine" wine C:\\\\Program\\ Files\\\\Adobe\\\\Reader\\ 11.0\\\\Reader\\\\AcroRd32.exe %f
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use your script in your desktop file:

```
Exec="full_path_and_script_name" %f
```

and change your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/wine "C:\\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "$1"
```

Note the double quotes for `$1`.

Comment: It's better. The script works every where, the .desktop file works like before.